# Packages for API level

Tags: installation, android-sdk

[image]
Hi, I'm new to Android development studio. My question is, if I am not using Android Emulator then do I need to install only these checked packages for every API level ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is the actual SDK, which is the source code, so definitely install it if you are targetting that API level. About Google API, depends on the use case. If you are going to talk to the internet or use Play Services you will need them for sure

Comment: Ok. It means Android SDK platform and sources for Android SDK of API levels which I want to use. What about Google API? Do I need to install that also ?